# Ограничение минимального и максимального значений в массиве numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pillow, pil

Как сделать так, чтобы при добавлении значения к красному каналу пикселя он не становился нулевым?

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


rd = int(input())
gd = int(input())
bd = int(input())

img1 = np.copy(Image.open("./Images_processing/image.jpg"))
img = img1.copy()
img[..., 0] += rd
img[..., 1] += gd
img[..., 2] += bd
a = np.where(img <= 255, img, 255)
b = np.where(a >= 0, a, 0)
img = Image.fromarray(b)
img.save("./Images_processing/image1.jpg")
```

Вот тут я пытаюсь изменить цвет пикселей так, чтобы если он был больше 255, то оставался 255, а если меньше 0, то оставался 0. Но numpy меняет эти значения (если > 255 - то на 0, если < 0, то на 255). Как можно было бы это исправить?

Пример:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


rd = 255
gd = 0
bd = 0

img1 = np.copy(Image.open("frame.jpg"))
img = np.clip(img1, 0, 255)
print(img[-1], 'img')
img[..., 0] += rd
img[..., 1] += gd
img[..., 2] += bd
print(img[-1], 'img')
img = Image.fromarray(img)
img.save("image1.jpg")
print(b[-1], 'b')
img = Image.fromarray(b)
img.save("image1.jpg")
```

Вывод:

```
[[70 64 64]
 [67 61 61]
 [67 61 61]
 ...
 [49 38 42]
 [52 41 45]
 [44 33 37]] img1

[[69 64 64]
 [66 61 61]
 [66 61 61]
 ...
 [48 38 42]
 [51 41 45]
 [43 33 37]] img2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом `numpy.clip()`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([256, -1])
res = np.clip(a, 0, 255) # первый аргумент - массив, второй - минимальное,
                         # третий - максимальное значение в массиве
print(res)
```

> [255   0]

Comment: Я поставил ограничение на массив побольше (img = np.clip(img1, -1000, 1000)) потом прибавил значение (img[..., 0] += self.rd), отфильтровал его 2 раза (a = np.where(img <= 255, img, 255); b = np.where(a >= 0, a, 0)) и потом попытался переделать его в картинку (img = Image.fromarray(b)), но он выдал эту ошибку: TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 3), <i2. Я попробовал задать ограничение на массив как вы сказали (от 0 до 255), но он всё равно обнуляет значение, если оно становится больше, чем 255.

Comment: Из вашего объяснения не все понятно. Вам нужно в вопросе воспроизвести конкретный пример с конкретными данными.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: я не понял, зачем в делаете np.clip(-1000,1000)? а потом еще np.where? вам нужно просто сделать np.clip(a, 0, 255). без np.where и т. д.

Comment: Опять отредактировал. Видите, там значения остаются почти такими же, хотя я прибавил 255 к красному каналу, они должны быть 255.

Comment: @strawdog В вашем примере по умолчанию создаётся массив данных типа `int64`, а у картинок тип данных `uint8`, отсюда и все приколы. )

Answer (score 3):

У вас просто происходит **переполнение типа данных**. Изначально данные картинки имеют тип `np.uint8`, это целый беззнаковый байт - значения от `0` до `255`. Если у вас, например, компонента имеет значение `255` и вы добавите к ней `1`, то произойдёт **переполнение** и значение станет не `256`, как вы ожидаете, а `0`. И наоборот, если вы из `0` вычтете `1`, то получите не `-1`, а `255`.

```
# uint8 [0, 255]
255 + 1 -> 0
  0 - 1 -> 255
```

Теперь как это исправить. **Повысьте тип данных** до **знакового большей разрядности** (это будет `int16`) прежде чем делать расчёты:

```
img = img1.copy().astype(np.int16)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Теперь расчёты будут идти без переполнения, так, как вы ожидаете:

```
#int16 [-32768, 32767]
255 + 1 -> 256
  0 - 1 -> -1
```

Но после расчётов нужно будет **вернуть тип данных** обратно, чтобы сохранить картинку. Данные в этот момент у вас уже приведены в диапазон типа `uint8` `0-255`, поэтому можно спокойно преобразовывать, данные не "испортятся" при преобразовании в более *узкий* тип:

```
img2 = Image.fromarray(b.astype(np.uint8))
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```